# How do I search for elements whose collection contains another element in Grails?

Tags: grails, collections, grails-orm

Let's say I have a domain class called "User" which can follow other "User" objects. It does so having a field specified as:

```
def hasMany=[followedUsers:User]
```

I need to do the reverse (find all User objects that follow a specific User object) without setting up the reverse relationship, since it is not a use case performed often. I tried to do something like this, using closures:

```
User.findAll { it.followedUsers.contains(userInstance) }
```

but this always returns all users in the database, regardless of their follow status. I tried doing with HQL but failed miserably as well.

Could anyone give me a quick pointer on the simplest way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this HQL query:

```
User.executeQuery(
   'select u from User u where :follower in elements(u.followedUsers)',
   [follower: userInstance])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up doing `def followers = User.findAll("from User where ? in elements(followedUsers)", [userInstance])`. I had actually tried this solution before but was missing the `elements()` call to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this syntax is much cleaner:

```
User.withCriteria { followedUsers{ eq('id', userInstance.id) } }
```