# Grails many-to-many - find all objects that do not contain specific object

Tags: grails

I have following domain model:

```
class Product {
    static hasMany = [ certificates : Certificate ]
}

class Certificate {
    static hasMany = [ products : Product ]
    static belongsTo = [ Product ]
}
```

How can I find all products that do not contain specific certificate? Preferably with criteria query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the approach that Burt suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946232/how-do-i-search-for-elements-whose-collection-contains-another-element-in-grails)

You can write your query like this:

```
 def p = new Product(message:"A")
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"1").save(flush:true) )
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"2").save(flush:true) )
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"3").save(flush:true) )
 p.save(flush:true)

 p = new Product(message:"B")
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"1").save(flush:true) )
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"2").save(flush:true) )
 p.save(flush:true)

 p = new Product(message:"C")
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"1").save(flush:true) )
 p.addToCertificates (new Certificate(message:"2").save(flush:true) )
 p.save(flush:true) 


def cer= Certificate.findByMessage("3")
Product.executeQuery(
'select p from Product p where :certificate not in elements(p.certificates)',[certificate: cer])
```

Output:

Result: [B, C]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Certificate certificate = Certificate.findTheSpecificOne()

def c = Product.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
  createAlias("certificates", "c", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
  not {'in'("c", certificate)}
}
```