# How to get a count of records in child table with a where clause

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I've got two table domains `color` and `shade` with color `hasMany [shades: Shade]` and shade `belongsTo [color: Color]`

and I've got the following data:

```
ID     color_name    color_type
----    --------      ----------
22       RED           CRAYON
23       GREEN         PAINT
45       GREY          CRAYON

ID     color_id       shade_name     is_available
---    ----------     -------------   ----------
2      22              DARK           false
3      22              LIGHT          true
4      23              DARK           true
5      23              LIGHT          true
6      45              DARK           false
7      45              LIGHT          false
```

How can I build a criteria to find out how many colors have X shades unavailable? Where X is the number of shades unavailable?

So, based on the example above:

If I pass `1` I would get back:

```
ID     color_name    color_type
----    --------      ----------
22       RED           CRAYON
```

However, if I pass `2` I would get back:

```
ID     color_name    color_type
----    --------      ----------
45       GREY          CRAYON
```

Comment: See if this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074841/grails-many-to-many-find-all-objects-that-do-not-contain-specific-object/17088124#17088124) work for you

Comment: I'm looking for a criteria query (or would prefer it). Not sure that post relates. I'm able to get the number of shades that are unavailable with this: `color.shades.isCleared.grep(false).size()` but I don't know how to fetch the number for a dynamic integer representing the number of un available shades

Comment: Have you tried @Alidad's approach, it is convenient as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it this way via HQL. Not sure how you would do it with criteria queries

```
Shade.executeQuery("Select distinct s.color \
                    from Shade s where \
                    (select count(distinct s2.name) \
                           from Shade s2 \
                           where s2.isAvailable = false \
                           and s2.color = s.color) = :numb", 
                    [numb: yourvalhere])
```

Comment: LOL. Word to word I was planning to give this answer when I saw the question. But Anthony wanted it in Criteria. I knew you would be first person to answer using HQL. :)

Comment: :) I'm building a criteria already based on other parameters so I would have preferred criteria. However, if its not possible then I'll make a separate if condition and use the HQL. Would still be beneficial to find out how to achieve this in criteria though

Comment: Ya - coming from a strong SQL background, I just can't "get" criteria queries. I've used them for simpler things and they are better for re-use, but HQL just makes so much more sense to me.

Comment: @Anthony You would be at ease once you become flexible to both Criteria and HQL. I (guess James as well) prefer HQL over Criteria in cases where direct access to associations is imminent.

Comment: ok, so is it good practice to have an app with both HQL and SQL. HQL is much easier to write but hard to understand :). I'll accept the answer (thanks James) but will play around with HQL to see if the same thing is possible with it.